# Options for the number of columns depends on screen resolution

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the options for the number of columns depends on screen resolution. (no_columns: 4,)
Here's the code for calling the function to initialize the plugin.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#blog-landing').pinterest_grid({
            no_columns: 4,  
            padding_x: 0,
            padding_y: 0,
            margin_bottom: 0,
            single_column_breakpoint: 1010
        });
    });
</script>
```

I try with this code:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {columns($(window).width());
if ($(window).width() < 1300) {
   no_columns = 4; } else {
 no_columns = 3; }});
```

but no success at all, Can someone help me implement this code.

Comment: Your `no_columns` is not a variable you have access to everywhere. You'd have to destroy and recreate your `pinterest_grid` every time the size changes. That's not a good solution. You'd be **FAR** better off using CSS for this and abandoning the `pinterest_grid` plugin, unless they added a way for this.

Comment: CSS not working for me I try column-count: 3; and browsers support very bad its K2 joomla on gantry framework only that plugin working so far all I need change no_columns from 4 to 3 below 1300px

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look on the *CSS media queries* and its ECMAscript interfaces. You could use those in a way like

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1300px)");
mql.addListener(function( obj ){
    if( obj.matches ) {
        no_columns = 4;
    } else {
        no_columns = 3;
    }
});
```